# Working code gives ClassCastException in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm trying to achieve these 3 things with the given *code-snippet*:

- Remove duplicates (from passed list `longSeq`)
- Discard elements violating bounds (`loBound < x < hiBound - 1`)
- Sort the resulting list

Code snippet:

```
val loBoung: Long = 0L
val hiBound: Long = Long.MaxValue
val longSeq: Seq[Long] = ...
...
val sortedTrimmedLongSeq: Seq[Long] =
  longSeq.toSet.toList.
  filter { p: Long => (loBound < p) && (p < hiBound - 1L) }.
  sorted
```

The given snippet works on a `Scala` *worksheet* but throws the following *stack-trace* in *unit test* (`MyClass.scala:104` line is the one containing `filter` operation in the above *snippet*):

```
MyClassTest:
[info] - makeContinuousRanges : converts sequence of big-ints to range segments *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
[info]   at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
[info]   at com.company.spark.sql.utils.MyClass$$anonfun$3.apply(MyClass.scala:104)
[info]   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filterImpl$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:248)
[info]   at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[info]   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
[info]   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
[info]   at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
[info]   at com.company.spark.sql.utils.MyClass$.makeContinuousRanges(MyClass.scala:104)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   ...
[info] ScalaTest
```

Is it because of the `scalatest.FunSuite` or is there a legitimate mistake?

---

**UPDATE-1**

As suggested by **@Dmytro Mitin**, I'm hereby providing more details.

I'm trying to convert a list of `Long`s into *continuous-ranges* as `range[i] = (seqLong[i] + 1, seqLong[i + 1])` (but lower & upper bounds can't be equal; there are other restrictions too, see code below).

> (assuming `loBound = 0` & `hiBound = Long.MaxValue`)
>
> Input-1 : [5, 10, 15]
>
> Output-1: [(0, 5), (6, 10), (11, 15), (16, Long.MaxValue)]
>
> ---
>
> Input-2 : [5, 10, 12, 20, 20]
>
> Output-2: [(0, 5), (6, 10), (11, 12), (13, 20), (21, Long.MaxValue)]
>
> ---
>
> Input-2 : [5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20]]
>
> Output-2: [(0, 5), (6, 13), (14, 20), (21, Long.MaxValue)]

Shown below is the function that I've written for this purpose that contains the problematic *code-snippet*.

```
def makeContinuousRanges(longSeq: Seq[Long],
                         loBound: Long = 0L,
                         hiBound: Long = Long.MaxValue
                        ): Seq[(Long, Long)] = {
    // [1] remove duplicates [2] fix bounds [3] sort
    val sortedTrimmedLongSeq: Seq[Long] =
      longSeq.toSet.toList.
      filter { p: Long => (loBound < p) && (p < hiBound - 1L) }.
      sorted

    // [1] create ranges [2] ensure that for all ranges [lo, hi], lo != hi
    val rangeSeq: Seq[(Long, Long)] = sortedTrimmedLongSeq match {
      case Nil =>
        Seq.empty[(Long, Long)]

      case head :: Nil =>
        Seq((loBound, head), (head + 1L, hiBound))

      case _ => {
        val continuousWithoutFirstWithoutLast: Seq[(Long, Long)] = sortedTrimmedLongSeq.zip(sortedTrimmedLongSeq.tail).
          map(tuple => (tuple._1 + 1L, tuple._2))
        val continuousWithFirstWithoutLast: Seq[(Long, Long)] = (loBound, sortedTrimmedLongSeq.head) +: continuousWithoutFirstWithoutLast
        val continuousWithFirstWithLast: Seq[(Long, Long)] = continuousWithFirstWithoutLast :+ (sortedTrimmedLongSeq.last + 1L, hiBound)

        continuousWithFirstWithLast
      }.filterNot(tup => tup._1 == tup._2)
    }

    // fill up any 'holes' created in the range due to that 'filterNot' step
    val smoothRangeSeqWithoutLast: Seq[(Long, Long)] = rangeSeq.zip(rangeSeq.tail).
      map { tup: ((Long, Long), (Long, Long)) =>
        (tup._1._1, tup._2._1 - 1L)
      }
    val smoothRangeSeqWithLast: Seq[(Long, Long)] = smoothRangeSeqWithoutLast :+ rangeSeq.last

    smoothRangeSeqWithLast
  }
```

The above method resides inside an `Object`, say `MyClass`. Like I said before, I've tested the function separately in a `Scala` *worksheet*. But it is faulting (on the line containing `filter`) in unit tests.

---

I'm using

- `Scala v2.11.11`
- `SBT v1.0.3`
- `"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.3"`

Comment: You should provide more details. Code you cited compiles and runs without errors.

Comment: After your update still can't reproduce. Runs without errors. https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/a4ac85dce2f112465a24cf9a45345516

Comment: Try to do `sbt clean` or reimport the project.